# How to return an object?

Tags: java, methods

The mission is =>

1. First character of the next word must match the last character of
   the previous word.
2. The word must not have already been saying.

`play`;  The method that takes in a word as an argument and checks if it is valid (the word should follow rules #1 and #2 above).

> If it is valid, it adds the word to the array and returns the array.
>
> If it is invalid (either rule is broken), it returns "game over" and
> sets the `game_over` to true.

The method is working on the mission. Thanks @MCEmperor.
**The solution is just to turn the method from String[] to Object.That was the mistake.**

```
String []arr;
int counter;
char lastword;
boolean game_over;

public Shiritori () {
    this.arr= new String[1];
    this.counter=0;
    this.lastword=' ';
    this.game_over=false;

}
public String[] play(String item) {  //Turn here  public Object play(String item)
    if(controltheitem(item)) {
        game_over=true; 
        return "game over"; //It's string therefore giving error of course.
    }
    if(item.charAt(0)!=lastword&&counter>0) {
        game_over=true;
         return "game over"; //It's string therefore giving error of course.
    }
    arr[counter]=item;
    lastword=arr[counter].charAt(arr[counter].length()-1);
    counter++;
    expandCapacity();
    return arr;       //It returns words truly.
    
}
```

I did not give you all the mission code. I just give that is just you need.

Comment: As the return type of the function then you also need to return the array of string.

Comment: @Abra you don't need to understand all of the code. I just publish what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by _"My method doesn't allow the mission. "_? you can't get inputs? the output doesn't match what you want? do you not get an output? you need to be clearer about your question.

Comment: Your assignment says that the method should return the words array, or "game over" in certain situations. The **only** way to actually achieve this, is to set the return type of the `play` method to `Object`.

Comment: @MCEmperor it's the answer thank you.

Comment: *"I did not give you all the mission code. I just give that is just you need."* <- No problem, exactly this is what you need to do: if you ask a debugging question, you need to show the smallest possible code which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the return type of the `play` method is array and you also want to return a String too. So, you just need turn the method from `String[]` to `Object`. So that you can return an array also a string too. As by changing to `Object` it will be of `genric` type:

```
public Object play(String item) {
    if(controltheitem(item)) {
        game_over=true; 
        return  "game over" ; //It's string therefore giving error of course.
    }
    if(item.charAt(0)!=lastword&&counter>0) {
        game_over=true;
         return "game over"; //It's string therefore giving error of course.
    }
    arr[counter]=item;
    lastword=arr[counter].charAt(arr[counter].length()-1);
    counter++;
    expandCapacity();
    return arr;       //It returns words truly.
    
}
```